# Pine Script: Checking for 2 consecutive indicator direction changes since event

Tags: pine-script

I simply want to do the following: Check whether a MA has crossed another and made 2 direction changes since then.

Example:

Step 1: Let's say MA20 crossing down MA50. That's the event from where we want to start looking back from (for every time this happened in the series).

Step 2: after event happened, did MA20 change direction

Step 3: after step 2, MA20 then changed direction again

I want to have a variable that is true when when the second MA20 direction change occurs. I'm totally new to pine/coding (days). Thx for the help in advance!

Here's what I have so far:

```
MA1 = ta.rsi(close, 5)
MA2 = ta.rsi(close, 26)

MA1_crossdown = ta.crossunder(MA1,MA2)
bars_since_event1 = ta.barssince(MA1_crossdown)

MA1_low = ta.lowestbars(MA1, bars_since_event1)
bars_since_event2 = ta.barssince(MA1_low)

MA1_high = ta.highestbars(MA1, bars_since_event2)
bars_since_event3 = ta.barssince(MA1_high)

final_turn_complete = (bars_since_event3 == 1) and MA1<MA1_high

plotshape(final_turn_complete, title='turns complete', style=shape.arrowdown, size=size.huge)
```

This doesn't seem to work. Also, I want to plot an arrow on every bar where final_turn_complete is true, not just since the last time the MA1_crossdown happened (backtesting).

Thx

Answer (score 0):

You're basically need 2 variables in your code:

1. `counter` - so you can count the amount of of time `ma20` changed direction. Keep in mind you'll need to use the `var` keyword so that this variable won't reset on each new bar.
2. a variable that checks the current direction.

After declaring those variables, you want to (if I understood you correctly), check if `ma20` is below `ma50` and if so then add 1 to the `counter` each time the direction of `ma20` changed. You can do that with the help of the `ta.change()` function with no problem.

At the end, you can just check the value of the `counter` variable to get a bool value.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay = true)
sma20 = ta.sma(close, 20)
sma50 = ta.sma(close, 50)

var counter = 0
bool sma_20_is_up = na

// check only if sma20 is above sma50, and if not then reset variables
if sma20 < sma50 and sma20[1] < sma50[1]
    sma_20_is_up := sma20 > sma20[1]

else
    counter := 0
    sma_20_is_up := na

if ta.change(sma_20_is_up)
    counter += 1

// do what ever you want at the first bar where `counter` is equal to 2
if counter == 2 and counter[1] == 1
    label.new(bar_index, low, text="BUY!", style=label.style_label_up, color = color.green)
```

Hope that helps